# Memory Dump not being written in C++ Release mode

Tags: c++, exception, crash-dumps

I've been using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu to get a dump file from my application which always crashes on another system.

So what I have is that Header file and CPP and in Debug Mode, but with no debugger attached, it asks me whether I want the dmp file created or not, and then crashes, but in release mode, it just crashes.

Basically the code I've been using is

```
void IndexFault(int n)
{
    unsigned char* smallArray = new unsigned char[4];
    printf((const char*)smallArray[n]);
}

MiniDumper* mDump = new MiniDumper("Dumpfile");

int main()
{
    IndexFault(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Again, if executing the exe created from Debug mode, I get the file just fine, with release I get nothing. This is with 64 bit code in both cases. I will apply this to my real code once this is working, but as of now, I cannot figure out what's going on. The Minidumpwriter I use is from the website as stated above.

Comment: In the page you link: only Windows XP and 2000 are mentioned and the dumper seems to only work with exceptions. This begs the question: are you sure it's supposed to work, to begin with ?

Comment: No, I do not, but it works for Debug absolutely fine.

Comment: I am no expert in VC++, but it could well be that the `Debug` mode includes extra checks (such as bounds check), that are not included in the `Release` mode (for performance reasons), and that your code may be relying on such a test.

Comment: I would use this `MiniDumper` and skin it to the minimum lines that still create a dump. Then see if that works in Release mode. If it works in Debug, but not in Release, you can try to turn Debug slowly into Release: enable optimisations, set NDEBUG, etc. You can try to debug the Release as well. If all else fails, post the skinned code here so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you missed this step:

> To call the API, you need to catch the crash by setting an unhandled exception handler with the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` API. This allows the filter function to be called at almost any time an unhandled exception occurs in an application. In certain unhandled exceptions, such as a double stack fault, the operating system will **immediately terminate the application without calling the filter or a JIT debugger**.

Anyway, I personally prefer to use WinDbg in such cases. Just attach to a remote process with it and get that dump.